# Listing all attachments for particular category

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I want to use this script to list all the attachments paths for posts of a particular category:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'     => 'attachment', 
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'category'      => 61
    ); 
    $the_attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ($the_attachments) {
        foreach ( $the_attachments as $post ) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            echo get_attached_file( $post->ID ) . "<br />";
        }
    } wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

But the problem is it doesn't do anything unless I remove the 'category' arg, in which case it shows ALL attachment paths regardless. But I only want it for category 61.

I've triple checked and there are indeed posts that contain attachments in category 61.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Category is not taxonomy for `attachment` post type. `post` and `attachment` are two different post types and `category` is attached to `post` and `attachments` are children of `post`.

So first get the all post in that category

```
$cat_posts = get_posts(array(
    'category' => 61,
    'numberposts' => -1
));
```

Create the post IDs array so we can use in `WP_Query`

```
$parent_ids = array_map('get_post_ids', $cat_posts);

function get_post_ids($post_obj) {
    return isset($post_obj->ID) ? $post_obj->ID : false;
}
```

Now get all the children of all parent IDs

```
$the_attachments = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent__in' => $parent_ids,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
));
```

Display the attachments

```
if ($the_attachments) {
    foreach ( $the_attachments as $my_attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($my_attachment->ID);
    }
}
```

> Note: `post_parent__in` is only available from version `3.6`

Comment: Bravo, it works like a charm, and props for the explanation. I didn't realise categories don't have taxonomy for attachment post types.